# splash screen is not working in android 6

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have added splash screen in my app but the app crashes when is run on Android 6. The interesting thing is that the app runs fine on Android 9.
Don't know what to do.
Target SDK - 28.
min SDK= 19

it is showing error on oncreate method while run app on android 6

splash.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class splash extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // it showing error here.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent splashintent=new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(splashintent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
}
```

logs

```
06-22 16:17:30.930 10294-10294/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.napps.wallpaper, PID: 10294
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.napps.wallpaper/com.napps.wallpaper.splash}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07009e
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07009e
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1595)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at com.napps.wallpaper.splash.onCreate(splash.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6298)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: And what is the error? To receive help from StackOverflow community make sure you follow [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and that your question presents [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to provide stack trace too.

Comment: ok.  so now i have added logs you can now watch whats happening

Comment: You;re missing `resource(string, drawable, layout)` or it might be anything.

Comment: add activity_splash layout ..error is in your xml file

Comment: add your layout file activity_splash.xml

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying

Comment: did you add any images in your layout?

Comment: yes is it causing any problem??

Comment: yes it could be. remove it and run your application

Comment: also check if the image is in drawable or in drawable-21 etc.

Comment: you were right i have removed image it worked but why i cannot add image??

Comment: can you confirm that there is nothing next to imagename  like this : imagename(drawable-21)

Comment: no my image name is not having any such name . also i have my image in my drawable folder only not in drawable-21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be problem with your drawable Image. While copying image Please check the folder in which you are copying.
Try to add the image in drawable folder not  drawable-21

I would suggest to remove old image and Add Image again to proper directory.